# Can you use joins to create a table that includes missing values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am looking to join multiple tables while maintaining null values where a value was not found. For example, if I have weekly player scores stored, I want to create table based on all players in the current event, regardless of whether they were in the previous events.

I've tried a number of join variations, but haven't found anything that works.

**EventRoster**

```
Player     Salary
------     ------
P1         10000
P2         20000
P3          5000
```

**LastWeek**

```
Player     Position
------     --------
P1         3
P2         5
P4         6
```

**TwoWeeksAgo**

```
Player     Position
------     --------
P1         20
P3         15
P4         2
```

Expected output:

```
Player     Salary     LastWeekPos     TwoWeeksAgoPos
-----      ------     ----------      --------------
P1         10000      3               20
P2         20000      5               -
P3          5000      -               15
```

I can only imagine building the expected output is feasible, but I'm likely taking the wrong approach. Any guidance on how to get moving on this?

Comment: Can you provide a query that you've tried?

Comment: Do you *really* have a table called `LastWeek` and `TwoWeeksAgo`? What about thrree weeks ago, or even four? If so, the real problem is the design. You should have 1 table, instead of the 2+ in the example, and have a column that denotes the week (number?) of the data. Then you simply need a (dynamic) pivot. Fix the design first, then the solution.

Comment: @Larnu I do have it set up this way temporarily just for a quick proof of concept for a class assignment. The end state will have tables that are stat specific (around 300 stats) with weekly updates to the tables that include a date column. Thanks for pointing out the importance of solid design before I let things get out of control!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Larnu pointed out, it is a little unusual to have a table for each week. If you're going to keep this database indefinitely, you should update your design.

That being said, the following returns exactly what you asked for.

```
select rst.Player,  rst.Salary, wk1.position LastWeekPos, wk2.position  TwoWeeksAgoPos
from EventRoster rst
 left join LastWeek wk1
   on wk1.player = rst.player
 left join TwoWeeksAgo wk2
   on wk2.player = rst.player
```

[See how it works in this Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24209/1)

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Wow. Thanks Lars. Huge oversight on my part as I discounted Left join early on when I couldn't get it to cooperate and instead foolishly moved to inner joins. Thanks for the quick response and getting me back on track. :-)